# Ubuntu 16.10 random folders appearing in home

Tags: dual-boot, 16.10, windows-10, home-directory

I'm using an ASUS Zenbook PRO UX501, with dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.10.

From time to time, I notice there are random two letters folders created in my home folder, things like `fe`, `5c`, `3a`, which I did not create.

Most times they're empty, and sometimes they contain 1 file with `.file` extension, and names like `3af7d9f464463e89033e53c998d67188a262abe6.file`

I don't know if it has anything to do with Windows 10, but I think they appear after I booted on Windows and then back in Ubuntu, although I'm not sure.

What are they? And why do they appear?

Comment: 1. Windows: no. They never allowed to write to foreign filesystems. 2. did you install bleachbit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's just not enough information from what you've provided to even begin to guess unless someone has experienced this exact condition.

With that said, I would recommend you set up `auditd` and monitor your home folder to identify the process creating the files.

That process as well is too involved to delineate in an answer "how to", so here are some references:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/auditd.8.html
https://linux-audit.com/configuring-and-auditing-linux-systems-with-audit-daemon/
https://www.linux.com/learn/customized-file-monitoring-auditd

So the concept is:

- Install and configure `auditd` to monitor your home folder
- Once the file(s) are created, inspect the `auditd` log to identify the cause of file creation

UPDATE:

Found this - if you are a Spotify user possibly the culprit . . . .

https://superuser.com/questions/572176/mysterious-folders-with-two-letters-hexadecimal-names

Comment: Yes! It was the Spotify thing, changing the cache location did the trick.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Some application that you're running is using /home as /tmp and placing those files there, which later probably get deleted. Review which apps are running at the time you see those folders. Check the create/modification date of the folders to get closer to the time that some app created them, to help figure this out.

When you see those folders getting created, you could use `terminal`...

```
lsof > open_file_report.txt
grep ".file" open_file_report.txt
```

to figure it out. `lsof` shows all open files and places that information in a file, and `grep` searches for a text string in that file.